# import multiple csv to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I know how to import a CSV file as a collection using mongoimport in shell/cmd prompt, or using GUI such as 3T studio.
each line is a document with headerline as their title.

For example a csv file name Data.csv
headerline and content are as follow:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh7Zc.png)

It can be done very easily using the above method if it is for just one file.

May I know is there a way to import multiple files (few hundred) where it can.
-Separate each file as one collection
-Use file name as collection name
-Import all contents as each documents under the collections

Best is can use nodejs, but other method are more than welcome.

Thank you.

update

```
for i in `ls ~/te/*.csv`;  do 
   ./mongoimport -d test $i --type=csv --headerline  ; 
done
```

---

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var yourscript = exec('bash mongoin.sh /te',
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(`${stdout}`);
        console.log(`${stderr}`);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash:

```
for i in `ls ~/Desktop/*.csv`;  do 
   ./mongoimport -d local $i --type=csv --headerline  ; 
done
```

In batch:

```
forfiles /p c:\te /m *.csv /c "cmd /c mongoimport -d local @file --type csv --headerline"
```

Where

```
 ~/Desktop/*.csv is the folder where the csv files are located.
```

And **local** is the mongodb database to import to.

The name of the collection will be picked up by the base filename of each csv file.

Put the content of the bash code in a script, say *mymongo.sh*:

```
for i in `ls $1`;  do 
   ./mongoimport -d local $i --type=csv --headerline  ; 
done
```

And then call it from node, with the following code:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var yourscript = exec('bash mymongo.sh /Users/niko/Desktop',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(`${stdout}`);
            console.log(`${stderr}`);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
}});
```

or on windows, with the code in *mymongo.bat*

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var yourscript = exec('cmd /c c:/te/mymongo.bat',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(`${stdout}`);
            console.log(`${stderr}`);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
}});
```

Comment: Thank you. As I am still quite new to this. Where did I put this? into the app.js? do i need to include anything? A more detailed program will be appreciated. Apologized for the trouble. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I put the bash into the folder "te" under C drive directly and put the CSV files in too. the edited code is what I have done.However, nothing happen. anything wrong?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to trouble you. Do you mind advise me further? Thank you.

Comment: added non-tested windows setup.

Answer (score 1):

This is python version of it.

```
import os
import subprocess

# directory of files
dir_files = 'C:\data'
# create list of all files
_, _, fns = next(os.walk(dir_files))
files = [os.path.join(dir_files, fn) for fn in fns]
# mongotool address
mongotool = r'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongoimport.exe'
# name of mongodb database
mydatabase = 'mydatabase'
# name of mongodb collection
mycollection = 'mycollection'
# import all files to mongodb
for fl in files:
    commands =[mongotool, '--db', mydatabase,
               '--collection', mycollection,
               '--file', fl,
               '--type', 'tsv',
               '--headerline']
    subprocess.Popen(commands, shell=True)
```